# What are the differences between ways of writing OpenMP sections?

Tags: c++, openmp, icc

What (if any) differences are there between using:

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for simd
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
        }
    }
```

and:

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    }
```

Or does the compiler(ICC) care?

I know that the first one defines a parallel section and than a for loop to be divided up and you can multiple things after the loop. Please do correct me if I'm wrong, still learning the ways of openmp..

But when would you use one way or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, if you only have 1 for-loop that you want to parallelise use `#pragma omp parallel for simd`.

If you want to parallelise multiple for-loops or add any other parallel routines before or after the current for-loop, use:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Other parallel code

    #pragma omp for simd
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
        }

    // Other parallel code
}
```

This way you don't have to reopen the parallel section when adding more parallel routines, reducing overhead time.